# Firebase Auth Not Found

Tags: android

Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found

I have updated all my SDK tools including Google play services. Checked my internet manifest file.
Then also it's not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your app-level build.gradle file. Usually shown as **build.gradle (Module: app)**. Check if it has the two lines mentioned below. If there's none, add those.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I have checked it... I wanted to know about system images do I need to have it? x86 images

Comment: If you're talking about Android emulator, then you do usually need x86 images. Else if you use only physical Android device to test your app, you don't need it.

Comment: I tried everything then also it's showing the same error

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't catch the situation. Perhaps you edit the question and give more details such as ```build.gradle``` content and error log.